# Why is there a bower lib folder for development, but it's not used in production?

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, bower

As a caveat let me make it clear that I'm ***not*** a front-end dev. On to the question...

In my ASP.NET Core app I can use `bower` to get `jQuery`, `Bootstrap`, etc. These files will then go into the `wwwroot/lib/` folder. Then in my views I can reference these like so:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
</environment>

<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
</environment>
```

For staging and production it's recommended to use a CDN so in this case I use the Microsoft ajax CDN. What I don't understand is why use bower/npm for `boostrap` or `jQuery`, when you could just use the CDN for development too.

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.js" />
</environment>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Cause you'll be unable to do any development when you have no internet connection. And for certain type of applications you want to create your own bundles, i.e. you could pipe all of your *.js files into a single file and minify it rather than have many smaller files that needs to be downloaded when a user visits the page and in bigger frameworks you may want to only include modules you really need rather than have the whole thing. This also applies in cases where you load modules dynamically, then you want to load it from your own server rather than from a CDN